# Move Constructor, move vector between two objects using std::move?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I have an object something like the following and I'm trying to implement a move constructor for so you can have an insert for `std::vector<Mesh>`.

```
struct Mesh
{    
    std::vector<Vector3> vPoint;
    bool Valid;

    Mesh(Mesh&& other)
    {
        vPoint = std::move(other.vPoint);
        Valid = std::move(other.Valid);
    }
};
```

Is this the correct way? 
And if so what is the value of other.Valid after std::move operates on it?

Edit:

Also if I have an instance of this object do I need to use std::move in the following scenario?

```
std::vector<Mesh> DoSomething()
{
    Mesh mesh; //Imagine vPoint is filled here to

    std::vector<Mesh> meshes;
    meshes.push_back(std::move(mesh)); // Here is my question, std::move? or just pass mesh here?

    return meshes;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to `move` a `bool`?

Comment: @us2012 I'm just curious what happens with `std::move<bool>` or other integral types. Does it copy the value to `this.Valid` and then set `other.Valid` to the default value of bool (aka false)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should write your move constructor as follows:

```
Mesh( Mesh&& other )
: vPoint( std::move( other.vPoint ) )
, Valid( std::move( other.Valid ) )
{}
```

The disadvantage of assignment within the constructor body as opposed to using the constructor initializer list is that in the former case the member objects of the `Mesh` object that you're moving to are default constructed and then assigned to within the body. In the latter case they're constructed directly from the result of the `std::move` call.

You shouldn't read from an object, be it an integral type, or a more complex object, after moving it. Such objects exist in an unspecified state.

Comment: Ok thank you, but what about within the Move Assignment operator? Is `vPoint = std::move(other.vPoint)` appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

(partial answer - answering the bit about `move`ing `bool`)

[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) has the following to say about `std::move`:

> The library code is required to leave a valid value in the argument,
>   but unless the type or function documents otherwise, there are no
>   other constraints on the resulting argument value. This means that
>   it's generally wisest to avoid using a moved from argument again.

So you cannot rely on a `bool` to be either `true` or `false` after `move`ing it.

Comment: Ah ok thank you, from testing it appears that built-in types do not have a move constructor so `bool b = std::move<bool>(other.b)` is basically just an assignment.

Comment: An assignment meets all the requirements for a move and there doesn't seem to be any way to improve on it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yeah I was hoping for a compiler warning or etc stating that std::move() will be downgraded to assignment only when no move-constructor is available for the type.

Comment: @NtscCobalt The hope for a warning is probably the result of the unfortunate name of `std::move` - it should really be called `std::obtain_rvalue_reference`. The compiler has no way of knowing (short of computing a full call graph and probably a lot of further semantic analysis) whether the obtained reference will be used to move stuff.